# Output current capability of LDO

Tags: power-supply

If an LDO generates 3.3V/300mA output voltage and current, what is the input current of the LDO?

Must I give more than 300mA current at the input?

Comment: probably will need 301 mA if CMOS LDO.

Answer (score 2):

Your powersupply must deliver at least 300mA if you are expecting 300mA out of the regulator.

The regulator doesn't generate the output current.  It reduces the voltage and passes current from the power supply.

---

Low drop out (LDO) regulators are a subclass of linear regulators.  All linear regulators require a voltage difference between input and output (the input must be higher than the output by some amount.)  That is the "drop out."  LDO regulators can operate with a small difference between input and output.

Please differentiate between linear regulators and LDO regulators.   If you mean just any linear regulator, call it a linear regulator.  Only call it an LDO if you **really** mean "a  regulator with the low dropout characteristic."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when calculating total input current to the regulator you should account at least for the following:

1. Current delivered to the load.
2. Ground pin current (look for it in the regulator datasheet).
3. If the regulator is adjustable, current used by adjustment elements (usually resistors).

Some regulators require a minimum load for stability reasons. This minimum load sometimes is achieved through the adjustment elements (in the case of adjustable regulators) or simply with a resistor at the output. You might need to include this into the calculation too.

If you simply want to calculate the the total input current requirement, then take maximum current that can be delivered at the output by the regulator and add the ground pin current. Then calculate how much current can be delivered to the load by substracting the current drawn by the adjustment elements / minimum load from the maximum output current of the regulator.